# I have an exact string as say "November 4, 2010" and I want to compare it with today's date in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How can one convert a string "November 4, 2010" and not "MMMM d, YYYY" to [`NSDate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for comparison?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `NSDateFormatter`, for this behaviour.

eg.

```
NSString *string = @"November 4, 2010";
[NSDateFormatter setDefaultFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_0];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"%B %e, %j";
NSDate *wantedDate = [formatter dateFromString:string];
```

[[Date date] compareWithDate:wantedDate]; // will return basically, what you want

See the [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class reference, and the [Data Formatting Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1). For background information about date formatting see: [here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: What is most pertient is the full date formatting guide: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns